# When multiplying two or more terms in an integral, can I calculate the terms seperately and then multiply?

Tags: calculus, multiplicative-function

For example, say I have an equation that is $\int_0^\infty x g(x)f(x)dx$

Can I calculate each term seperately, say for example my maximum $x$ value is 500.

Is it something like $500\int_0^{500} g(x)\int_0^{500} f(x)dx$?

I could not find a rule for this sort of behavior online, and my background is not in mathematics.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such rule. We can easily differentiate a product, but not easily integrate it. The most important technique for integrating products is integration by parts.

Comment: It's always a good idea to think of a "dummy" example. Let's say that $g(x) = x$. If integration could be separated at multiplication, you would have
$$
\int x^2 \, dx = \int x \cdot x \, dx = \int x\, dx \cdot \int x\, dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}x^2
$$
But everyone knows that $\int x^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3$ (I left out the "plus constant" to make this shorter). So just thinking about this for a few seconds, you can see that this is not true.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. It's easy to see even in very simple case:

$$
2 = \int_0^2 1\times 1 \, dx \neq \left(\int_0^2 1\,dx\right)\left(\int_0^2 1\,dx\right) = 2\times 2
$$

Since an integral is essentially a sum, what you propose is something like:
$$
a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 = (a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2).
$$
I hope you can see why this doesn't work.